# Display change in value of a cell in adjacent cell using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel sheet that display's price on certain items in a column by looking up amazon API using excel vba. The price of may change overtime. So I am trying to display the difference in prices each time i run my macro, in a cell adjacent to the cell that displays price.
But I am not sure how to achieve this. Can any body guide me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a sample, it must be adapted to your schema and data layout.  Say the prices are stored in column **A** from **A1** to **A100**.  Say you already have a macro called *RefreshData()* that updates column **A**.  In **B1** enter:

```
=C1-A1
```

and copy down.  This macro store the current values in column **C** before refreshing the data:

```
Sub DoUpdate()
    Range("A1:A100").Copy Range("C1")
    Call RefreshData
End Sub
```

Column **B** will display the price difference.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

Let's say your data are in a range A2:A10

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Range("A2:A10")

rng.Offset(0,1).Value = rng.Value
```

Run this before you run your original macro to store the values in an adjacent column before the values change. You may need to make the range dynamic, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing you code, I cannot give a detailed answer. However, I ran across a similar problem once, not using Amazon API though, but a sharepoint connection.

If the amazon api is somewhat similar to the sharepoint stuff, I guess it refreshes cells when you click "update", or run the update sub. In that case you will have to either create an array to store the old prices in vba (very slow process), and then write them to your table, or create a separate tab where you store the item-lastPrice combination.

I ended up storing not only current price but all prices and the date/time of the price, to be able to see change over time.

For the copying of data itself using VBA, either of the above methods should work. In my initial code I used vba loops :-p, but copying using excel functionality is much faster.